# What would cause a gravitational wave that is measured on Earth by "macro-sized" instrumentation?

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves

LIGO has successfully measured the effect of gravitational waves moving through the Earth from a very distant source.  Such measurements require extremely precise and calibrated instrumentation because the effect is exceedingly small.

Earthquakes, on the other hand, are much more easily measured.  Every now and then I receive an e-mail notice of a small tremor (1 to 3 on Richter) in our area (Puget Sound area, Washington state).  And, no one feels this small quake, only the instruments detect it.

My question, what kind of galactic event (source, how large, how far from us) could cause a gravitational wave passing through Earth that is just below the level of human observation (without instruments).  In other words, like the 1 to 3 Richter Earthquake that most do not feel, what would cause a gravitational wave of such magnitude just below human sensory capabilities?

Follow-up question:  How disastrous would such a gravitational wave be for the integrity of planet Earth?

Comment: the follow-up depends on the frequency, if it were around 22.4$\,\mu$Hz..Earth might be used to it.

Comment: @JEB 22.4 $\mu$Hz seems kind of small.   If that were instead 22.4 MHz, I could listen to it on my transceiver -- that is just above the 15-meter amateur radio band.

Comment: Isn’t the real question what event would produce gravitational waves we can actually feel?

Comment: @K7PEH that is the frequency of the Principal lunar semidiurnal tide ($M_2$), which could look like a gravitational wave to someone fixed on the surface (but take that with a grain of NaCl).